# НЕ скачивается фото из респонса

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

```
import time
import requests
from pprint import pprint

def get_photo():
    vk_access_token = '958eb5d439726565e9333aa30e50e0f937ee432e927f0dbd541c541887d919a7c56f95c04217915c32008'
    url1 = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get'
    params = {
            'owner_id': 552934290,
            'access_token': vk_access_token,
            'v': 5.131,
            'album_id': 'wall',

    }
    r = requests.get(url1, params=params)
    # pprint(r.json()['response']['items'])
    for i in r.json()['response']['items']:
        # pprint(i['sizes'])
        for k in i['sizes']:
            if k['type'] == 'z':
               pprint(k['url'])
               file_url = k['url']
               filename = file_url.split('/')
               api = requests.get(file_url)

               with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(api.content)
get_photo()
```

Пытаюсь скачать фото из респонс, но вывод вот такой

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Alexey Karneenko\Netology\сourse_Work.py", line 30, in <module>
    get_photo()
File "C:\Users\Alexey Karneenko\Netology\сourse_Work.py", line 28, in get_photo
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Не могу понять в чем конкретно ошибка, ожидается строка, но там ссылка и она вроде как строка. Помогите советом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filename = file_url.split('/')
...
with open(filename, 'wb') as f
```

После использования `split` у вас в `filename` оказывается **список**. А список нельзя использовать в качестве имени файла, о чём и говорит ошибка:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Возможно, вы имели в виду что-то такое (взять строку после последнего символа `/` в качестве имени файла):

```
filename = file_url.split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, помогло, но теперь OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: в качестве аргумента ссылка на фото которое надо скачать. Ссылка кликабельна и работает отлично. В чем сейчас дело ?

Comment: Покажите, что у вас в `file_url` и в `filename`. А также в какой строке и на каком коде теперь ошибка. Вероятно, там в `url` какие-то недопустимые для имени файла символы. Ну или не знаю, в общем нужна конкретика.